# Correlating items from two arraylists in Java

Tags: java, android, arraylist

In my android app I have a spinner (drop-down) that contains category names.
User selects a category by its name, say "Food and Drink"

those categories are contained in an ArrayList categoryNamesArray

there is another ArrayList categoryIDsArray which contains the category ID integers.

The ordering for both matches, meaning category 1 is category Automotive, which it is supposed to be.

I need to send the category ID to the database, when the user chooses a category by name. How can I do that.

It gets more complicated with Subcategories, because their IDs start with 40-something.

[image]

Additional info:

I pull the ids from the server and put them in an arraylist, then I pull the category names from the server and put them in another arraylist. Then put the two arraylists in one Object[] and pass them to the activity that needs them

Comment: sounds like you should create a Category object, and have an Array of those which the user then picks from.

Comment: sounds promising, can you draft an example?

Comment: why to get the ID and name in different arraylist ?

Comment: I pull the ids from the server and put them in an arraylist, then I pull the category names from the server and put them in another arraylist. Then put the two arraylists in one Object[] and pass them to the activity that needs them

Comment: Your solution sounds terrible.  Instead create a class that contains the category name and the category id and have one list (or array) containing objects of that class.

Comment: you probably receive the click event in a onListItemClick or somthing, in which you have the `position` of the click element. Use it to get the id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are, for legacy or some other reason, restricted to the ArrayList data structure, you can get the corresponding id by doing

```
String chosenName; // user selects this
Integer id = categoryIDsArray.get(categoryNamesArray.indexOf(chosenName));
```

But, it will be hugely better if you change the code to have either

1. A "Category" object (as suggested by Eluvatar), or
2. A `BiMap<Integer, String>` which is a bidirectional map enabling you to get the id from a name, and vice versa.

Comment: Im not restricted to anything, I just dont have sufficient Java knowledge and experience and Im working with what I know.

Comment: can you provide examples for the hugely better solutions?

Comment: Examples? Not off the top of my head right now. But, since the ID obviously has a one-to-one correspondence with the category name, a map is the natural data structure to maintain correspondence. Additionally, in a general scenario, the ID and name may not remain at the same index. e.g. 1 --> empty string or null, 2 --> first category name, 3 --> 2nd cat name, ...

Comment: should i create 100 objects for my 100 subcategories?

Answer (score 2):

Well you can start with the Category class as base class for both, main category and sub category

```
public abstract class Category
{

    String name;
    String id;
    // More common fields;
}

public class MainCategory extends Category
{
//Main Category Specific  extra variables and method implementations.

}

public class SubCategory extends Category
{
//sub Category Specific  extra variables and method implementations.

}
```

Then simply use ArrayList because it can take MainCategory as well as SubCategory.

Moreover, you can simply override the toString method and use the direct object in the list so that when user selects the checkbox you will have the complete object for use.