# LinkedHashSet<ItemCategory> and a Spinner in Android

Tags: java, android

For my android app I have spinners that provide list of product categories for the users to choose from

following this discussion: [Corelating items from two arraylists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21588821/corelating-items-from-two-arraylists-in-java)

I created a category object in the following fashion:

```
public class ItemCategory {

    private int id;
    private String name;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

I am storing all the ItemCategories in a LinkedHashSet and Im passing this LinkedHashSet to all the activities that need to display a spinner with categories.

Now, the question is, how do I populate the spinner with the names of those ItemCategory objects, and then, when a selection is made, I need to set the int newItemCategoryID to the corresponding ID from the same ItemCategory object?

this is how Im populating the spinner:

```
public class LoadSpinnerData {
    public static void loadSpinnerData(Context context, ArrayList<String> array, Spinner spinner) {

        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
                R.drawable.simple_spinner_item, array);

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter
                .setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // Attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    }
}
```

And this is how I pass that ArrayList to this spinner:

```
    categoriesInfo = new GetCategoriesFromDB(dbTools).execute().get(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    ArrayList<String> categoryNamesArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(ItemCategory itemCategory : categoriesInfo) {
        categoryNamesArray.add(itemCategory.getName());
    }
    LoadSpinnerData.loadSpinnerData(this, categoryNamesArray, sAddAnItemCategory);
```

The question is what do I do here:

```
sAddAnItemCategory.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

                newItemCategoryID = ????

            }

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to retrieve the element at position you can use `arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2)`.

In your specific case it will be:

```
ItemCategory item = (ItemCategory) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
newItemCategoryID = item.getId();
```

Edit:

```
public class LoadSpinnerData {
public static void loadSpinnerData(Context context, ArrayList<ItemCategory> array, Spinner spinner) {

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<ItemCategory> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ItemCategory>(context,
            R.drawable.simple_spinner_item, array);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(R.drawable.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
}
}
```

and

```
    categoriesInfo = new GetCategoriesFromDB(dbTools).execute().get(4000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);      
    LoadSpinnerData.loadSpinnerData(this, categoriesInfo, sAddAnItemCategory);
```

Comment: and what do I do with that element, so I can get the ItemObject id?

Comment: I just tried it and got a ClassCastException. What should I do?

Comment: as I think about it, Im populating the spinner with Strings, taken from an ArrayList, that is comprised of only the names from the ItemCategory objects

Comment: yes the problem is related to the Array. The simplest thing you can do is override toString inside ItemCategory and let it return the name, and change the Adapter in order that it will be an ArrayAdapter or ItemCategory.

Comment: I dont know how to to the second thing you mentioned